# Replacing an answer vs. updating an answer

Tags: discussion

I have answered a question, and based on feedback from the OP, most of my answer needs to be replaced/updated with the revised answer.  My question:  Should I append the new answer to the existing post so as to make the currently proposed answer as clear as possible; or should I leave the current answer and add on to the post with a clearly marked UPDATE section, which would have the advantage of showing the evolution of the answer as the question itself was clarified?  The thread in question is [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29761/how-to-design-tables-for-players-in-a-tournament), if that helps any.

Answer (score 4):

My preference would be to replace the *current answer completely* with your updated version.  I find it distracting to read previous versions in-line only to have my thought process derailed by a sudden **UPDATE** or **EDIT** marker followed by a completely new answer based on feedback from comments or further thought by the answerer.

All edits are tracked in a [public edit history](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq#editing) automatically.  There is little point in duplicating this feature in most cases.  Common sense is a good guide here.

Comment: Just repeating myself from our argument: I like to indicate my edits when it clearly refers to a comment stream.  Sometimes not only the result, but the way leading to it is very interesting.

Comment: @dezso Interesting and useful?  Or just interesting?  Future visitors may be less interested in the historical perspective than you imagine.  I might be wrong, but I think the number of cases where a substantial storyline is necessary for a good answer would be quite small.

Answer (score 1):

*Check the history ;-)*
Of course, you could let them sniff it out via the history link, if it's after the 5 minute window. That's your prerogative. If you think the old answer might have some bearing, feel free to leave it. But you can delete it too.